# Can I run an RMI client and RMI server by placing them in different packages on both ends?

Tags: java, rmi, package

Can my RMI client and server run when under different package names?  Currently they reside in different packages.  Is that going to cause problems?

Answer (score 4):

Certainly. You could have tried that for yourself. The only gotcha is that classes that are shared, such as the remote interfaces, must be in the same package at both ends.

Comment: But i need to run in different package on both ends.Is that possible ??

Comment: No, you don't *need* to do any such thing. You just desire it. The constraints are as stated above.

Answer (score -1):

yes. you can run.. Stub interfaces should be placed in client and skeleton interfaces should be placed in Server.

Comment: This answer is meaningless. There is no such thing as either a 'stub interface' or a 'skeleton interface'.